# Django Rest Framework "A valid integer is required."?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to default an empty string to a 0 or null during deserialization.

JSON

```
{
  'injuries': '6',
  'children': '2',
  'civilians': '',
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> "A valid integer is required."

models.py

```
from django.db import models    

class Strike(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    civilians = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    injuries = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    children = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Strike


class StrikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    civilians = serializers.IntegerField(default=0, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Strike
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Strike.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

main

```
serializer = StrikeSerializer(data=strike)
```

I tried manipulating data in create method, but the error gets raised before that. Where in the DRF structure can I override this, specifically convert '' to 0 or None?

Comment: Why are you posting a string to an integer field in the first place?

Comment: I'm getting a JSON file where integers are stored as strings, so when I deserialize I convert them to integers (I've updated the question). @DanielRoseman

Comment: I'm using DRF serializers for out of the box validation and instance saving, if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you omit the `civilians` entry and change the `Strike` model's field to `civilians = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)`

Comment: Tried it, the effect is still the same. I'm guessing default doesn't matter since the field got a specific value of '', thereby not triggering the default behaviour. @RossRogers

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to omit the `civilians` field too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a `CharField` and then convert to `int` in the validation method.

```
class StrikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    civilians = serializers.CharField(
            required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)

    def validate_civilians(self, value):
        if not value:
            return 0
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('You must supply an integer')
```

Comment: Thanks - this was very helpful after I made some adjustments - did you mean to use serializers.CharField instead of serializers.IntegerField?

Comment: It does fix my issue but for that, I have to change the field name. Is there any other way to implement validate_civilians in a field without changing the field ??

Comment: `civilians = serializers.IntegerField(default='', required=False)` this does not work without giving source name, hence I had to change the field name. which I really don't want to do

Comment: This is not an universal solution in validating an integer. What happens if I want to validate a boolean field with CharField? It looks more like a workarround for me. Mr Rossman correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @AlexM.M. Look at the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59841626/2251364) for an alternative

Answer (score 4):

You can use **to_internal_value** method to intercept the data before it is being validated.

```
class StrikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    civilians = serializers.IntegerField(default=0, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Strike
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if data.get('civilians') == '':
            data['civilians'] = 0

        return super(StrikeSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Strike.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: Instead of default, how about `allow_null=True` and set `data['civilians'] = None` in `to_interval_value`