# Django REST "A valid integer is required" on updating null=True IntegerField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I followed [Django Rest Framework "A valid integer is required."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753316/django-rest-framework-a-valid-integer-is-required) to setup `SpiderSerializer`, but seems not working, still getting  `{"min_word_count":["A valid integer is required."]}`

Request Payload    `{..., min_word_count:""}`

```
class Spider(models.Model):
    ...
    min_word_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=100,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )


class SpiderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    min_word_count = serializers.IntegerField(default='', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Spider
        exclude = ('category',)


    def validate_min_word_count(self, value):
        print('value1111111111111')
        print(value)
        if not value:
            return 0
        try:
            value = int(value)
        except ValueError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('You must supply an integer')
        return value
```

Comment: remove `default='',` from `min_word_count = serializers.IntegerField(default='', required=False)` You have already given at model

Comment: yes, just removing the whole line `min_word_count = serializers.IntegerField(default='', required=False)` also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min_word_count:""` is an empty string and thus not a valid number.
You could have `min_word_count: None` and add `allow_null=True` to the field declaration.

```
In [7]: class SpiderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   ...:     min_word_count = serializers.IntegerField(default='', required=False)
   ...:     

In [8]: s = SpiderSerializer(data={})

In [9]: s.is_valid()
Out[9]: True

In [10]: s = SpiderSerializer(data={'min_word_count': None})

In [11]: s.is_valid()
Out[11]: False

In [12]: s.errors
Out[12]: 
ReturnDict([('min_word_count',
             [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be null.', code='null')])])

In [13]: s = SpiderSerializer(data={'min_word_count': ""})

In [14]: s.is_valid()
Out[14]: False

In [15]: s.errors
Out[15]: 
ReturnDict([('min_word_count',
             [ErrorDetail(string='A valid integer is required.', code='invalid')])])
```

Comment: `min_word_count: None` works (in angularjs `<input type="number">` can returns null value for blank input, while `<input>` returns empty string), no need `allow_null=True`. I guess REST can detect `null=True` in the Model

Comment: yup, allow_null will be set if the model has null=True